# Getting historic information to create calculated column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Input:
Date        HomeTeam    AwayTeam        HomePoints  AwayPoints
2014-08-16  Arsenal     Crystal Palace  2           1
2014-09-13  Arsenal     Man City        2           2
2014-09-27  Arsenal     Tottenham       1           1
2014-10-18  Arsenal     Hull            2           2
2014-11-01  Arsenal     Burnley         3           0
```

I have a dataset that looks like the above. I want to create a column for the historic  game differential for both the HomeTeam and the AwayTeam (i.e. before the date of the given game instance). How exactly can I do this?

```
Expected output:
Date        HomeTeam    AwayTeam        HomePoints  AwayPoints  HomeDiff AwayDiff
2014-08-16  Arsenal     Crystal Palace  2           1           1        -1
2014-09-13  Arsenal     Man City        2           2           1         0
2014-09-27  Arsenal     Tottenham       1           1           1         0
2014-10-18  Arsenal     Hull            2           2           1         0
2014-11-01  Arsenal     Crystal Palace  3           0           4        -4
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: just added sorry about that

Comment: how you are calculating the HomeDiff and AwayDiff?

Comment: its the historic game differential for the home team and the away team

Comment: I see it in two steps - first create column only with differences `HomePoints  - AwayPoints` and later use `cumulative sum` - probably `df.cumsum()`

Comment: it would be simple if you create minimal working code with data directly in code so we could simply copy it and run it and test ideas to create solution.

Comment: as for me in `AwayDiff` should be `-1` in place of `0`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand values in `HomeDiff` and `AwayDiff` then you could do this in two steps.

- First calculate normal difference between `HomePoints` and `AwayPoints`.
- Next use `cumulative sum` - `.cumsum()`

like

```
df["H_A_diff"] = df["HomePoints"] - df["AwayPoints"]
df["HomeDiff"] = df["H_A_diff"].cumsum()

df["A_H_diff"] = df["AwayPoints"] - df["HomePoints"]
df["AwayDiff"] = df["A_H_diff"].cumsum()
```

or shorter

```
df["HomeDiff"] = (df["HomePoints"] - df["AwayPoints"]).cumsum()
df["AwayDiff"] = (df["AwayPoints"] - df["HomePoints"]).cumsum()
```

---

Minimal working code

```
text = '''Date        HomeTeam    AwayTeam        HomePoints  AwayPoints
2014-08-16  Arsenal     Crystal Palace  2           1
2014-09-13  Arsenal     Man City        2           2
2014-09-27  Arsenal     Tottenham       1           1
2014-10-18  Arsenal     Hull            2           2
2014-11-01  Arsenal     Burnley         3           0'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')

#df["H_A_diff"] = df["HomePoints"] - df["AwayPoints"]
#df["HomeDiff"] = df["H_A_diff"].cumsum()

#df["A_H_diff"] = df["AwayPoints"] - df["HomePoints"]
#df["AwayDiff"] = df["A_H_diff"].cumsum()

df["HomeDiff"] = (df["HomePoints"] - df["AwayPoints"]).cumsum()
df["AwayDiff"] = (df["AwayPoints"] - df["HomePoints"]).cumsum()

print(df)
```

Result

```
         Date HomeTeam        AwayTeam  HomePoints  AwayPoints  HomeDiff  AwayDiff
0  2014-08-16  Arsenal  Crystal Palace           2           1         1        -1
1  2014-09-13  Arsenal        Man City           2           2         1        -1
2  2014-09-27  Arsenal       Tottenham           1           1         1        -1
3  2014-10-18  Arsenal            Hull           2           2         1        -1
4  2014-11-01  Arsenal         Burnley           3           0         4        -4
```

Comment: What if it was average historic goal differential?

Comment: do you mean `(df["HomePoints"] - df["AwayPoints"]).mean()` or `df["HomeDiff"].mean()` ?